# CSS nav styling

Tags: html, css, nav

I am recreating Apple page from Youtobe video to learn more css and html. I encountered a problem with a styling of navigation.

My problem is that the nav section is too wide. As you can see on a first photo icons are a lot closer and in the middle. Not wide on a lenght of side as in photo 2(my code).

This is how  it sholud look like:
[image]

And How it looks:
[image]

I have the same code as a in video.
Link(Styling nav about 17:30):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEpF1nNz1l0&t=183s

This is mine:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: "SF Pro Text","Myriad Set Pro","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif
}

a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container{
    max-width: 98rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2.2rem;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1400;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.4rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    backdrop-filter: blur(2rem);
    
}

.nav-list{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 -1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="cointainer">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="nav-list nav-list-mobile">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <div class="mobile-menu">
                            <span class="line line-top"></span>
                            <span class="line line-botton"></span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link nav-link-apple"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-bag"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-list nav-list-mobile -->
                <ul class="nav-list nav-list-larger">

                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-hidden">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link nav-link-apple"></a>
                    </li>                    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Mac</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">iPad</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">iPhone</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Watch</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">TV</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Music</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sport</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Support</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-search"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-hidden">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-bag"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-list nav-list-larger -->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: It looks fine to me. [See screenshot](https://ibb.co/MGT8X0d)

Comment: My problem is that the nav section is too wide. As you can see on a first photo icons are a lot closer and in the middle. Not wide on a lenght of side as in photo 2(my code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a width of 80% to `.nav` and centered it in the `.container` class.

try adding the icons (I couldn't find them)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: "SF Pro Text","Myriad Set Pro","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif
}

a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

.cointainer {
    max-width: 98rem;
    padding: 0 2.2rem;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav {
    width: 80%
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1400;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.4rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    backdrop-filter: blur(2rem);
    
}

.nav-list{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 -1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="cointainer">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="nav-list nav-list-mobile">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <div class="mobile-menu">
                            <span class="line line-top"></span>
                            <span class="line line-botton"></span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link nav-link-apple"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-bag"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-list nav-list-mobile -->
                <ul class="nav-list nav-list-larger">

                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-hidden">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link nav-link-apple"></a>
                    </li>                    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Mac</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">iPad</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">iPhone</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Watch</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">TV</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Music</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sport</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Support</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-search"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-hidden">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-bag"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-list nav-list-larger -->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thank you. When I did copy your code I realized I made mistake in name container. In css I wrote cointainer.

Comment: Should I delite question in this situation?

Comment: No, don't worry about it. if I helped you please don't forget accept my answer :3